# Float a to left using css

Tags: html, css

I want to float four `a` element, but `float : left;` doesn't work:

```css
a.fred {
    height: 460px;
    min-width: 320px;
    display: block;
}
#content_new{
    margin: 50px auto;
    float: left;
}
.un{
    background-color: red;
}
.deux{
    background-color: #ffff00;
}
.trois{
    background-color: greenyellow;
}
.quatre{
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<div id="content_new">
    <a class="fred un" href="#">Item 1</a>
    <a class="fred deux" href="#">Item 2</a>
    <a class="fred trois" href="#">item 3</a>
    <a class="fred quatre" href="#">Item 4</a>
</div>
```

Any one have a solution to that?

Comment: What "doesn't work"?

Comment: Haha, you don't edit someones answer to thank them :D If it is the answer you are using, mark it as accepted when the time is up :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `float: left` for `a`:

```
a.fred {
    height: 460px;
    min-width: 320px;
    float: left;
}
```

So `display: block` is unnecessary.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3rphg9vw/)**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are asking, but you should put `float:left` in the `<a>`'s css if you want it applied to them:

```
a.fred {
    height: 460px;
    min-width: 320px;
    display: block;
    float:left;
}
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f0fvgo4t/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a new #content_new a:

```
#content_new a {
margin: 50px auto;
float: left;
}
```

?

[DEMO@JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r6o2wnhe/)